# When I click on the area is not displayed the correct text

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, automation

The method to click on the area is:

```
public CovTextContentDialog goToCovTextContentDialog(int index) {
    log.info("Click on Text area inside of preview");
    String parentWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
    WebElement textAreaElement;
    CovTextContentDialog covTextContentDialog;
    try {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions
            .frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(contentFrameBy));            
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions
            .visibilityOfElementLocated(getTextImageAreaByIndexBy(index)));
        textAreaElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(
            "//div[@id='detailscontent']/map/area[contains(@href, 'geomOrder=" + index + "&')]"));
        textAreaElement.click();
```

The text displayed is the geomOrder 16, but should display
[the text of geomOrder 14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4bq5.png).

Is there another way to click on the correct area?

Comment: it would be easier to help if you copied the code instead of printing it

Comment: Ok, I added the code

Comment: If `index` is 14, then based on this code `geomOrder=14` will be selected. So you have some code error that is beyond pasted code.

Comment: The geomOrder received is 14, but is not displayed the correct text, the others geomOrder are displayed correctly. I think that is overlaying

Comment: @ArielRojas : what I would suggest it to create a `List<WebElement>` for all the `area` in your code and then access each one of them to check if its an inconsistency with any specific case or not.

Comment: I tested with a List<WebElement> and there is the same problem. Is there issue of overlaying in selenium?